# How to check an event is true with v-if?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im want to use v-if statement to handle an event like this(If click a button and validate becomes true show a div):

```
<div v-if=btn v-on:click="validate">
      <v-progress-linear
        v-model="value"
        :active="show"
        :indeterminate="query"
        :query="true"
      ></v-progress-linear>
</div> (...)
```

What´s the correct way to do this?

Comment: Simply store the validation state in the component data, then reference that in the `v-if` binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-if` respond to `boolean` value.

example:

if your `v-model="validate"` in inputCheckbox/Button or `validate:true` initialised under `data()` as validation state

then your `v-if="validate"` is enough

P/S: This [sheet](https://www.vuemastery.com/pdf/Vue-Essentials-Cheat-Sheet.pdf) might save your troubles in future.